# Zoomy script not working in Joomla K2 site

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, joomla, joomla-k2

I have a Joomla K2 site, and when user clicks on the image in K2 it should be opened in a popup with k2. But now that doesn't work anymore and the problem is in the Zoomy script. Here is an [item from my site](http://zasvadba.mk/kategorii/ketering/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B5.html) can any body help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well I think the problem is that you have 5 versions of jQuery running lol. If you open the source using Firebug or Chrome's extension, you will be able to see. If the extensions you have have a jQuery parameter, turn 4 of them off, else use the following code to ensure that it's only embedded once:

```
<?php
  // load jQuery, if not loaded before
  if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
    JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
    $document =& JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "path_to_file/jquery-1.8.2.js");
  }
?>
```

**Update:**

Here are the jQuery files being embedded:

1. ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js
2. ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
3. /plugins/content/plg_zoomin/plg_zoomin/jquery-1.5.min.js
4. /modules/mod_sj_k2_accordion/assets/js/jquery-1.5.min.js
5. /plugins/system/onexitpopup/js/jquery.1.7.1.js

Im not sure where the 2 googleapis ones are coming from, but 1 is coming from a module called `mod_sj_k2_accordion` and the others are coming from 2 plugins. So find the plugins and either remove the jQuery reference or add the code I posted above instead. If you do use the code I posted above, please make sure you change the path **your** path.

Comment: do you know how to find which modules,plugins or components is adding the jquery scripts to disable them, or how to delete three of them?

Comment: @Darko - please see my updated answer. There are actually 5 versions being loaded.